# PHP: Create new array based on number of elements in cell and concat sequential cells with >1 element

Tags: php, arrays

PHP Question

ArrayAlpha:

```
        [0] => A
        [1] => B C
        [2] => D
        [3] => E F
        [4] => G H
        [5] => I J
```

New array should be:

```
  [0] B C
  [1] E F G H I J
```

**Condition 1**: If an ArrayAlpha cell contains two or more separate elements, then it will go into the new array.

**Condition 2**: Concatenate(with a space) a cell with the next cell, and the one after that etc.,  IF the next cell has 2 or more separate elements

Is there a simple way of doing this?

At the moment it looks like I need to create another array, count the elements in each cell of ArrayAlpha and place the answers into another array. Create yet another array and place the index of any cell with a value of 1 into the latest array, then using multiple for loops to generate the final array.

Comment: dont get it, why is B C not in the EFGHIJ?

Comment: Because the next cell in ArrayAlpha contains less than two elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, loop over the array and increment an index based upon a condition (if it has only 1 char), then concat the value onto the array.

For example: https://3v4l.org/kDtVF

```
<?php
$array = [
    0 => 'A',
    1 => 'B C',
    2 => 'D',
    3 => 'E F',
    4 => 'G H',
    5 => 'I J'
];

$new = [];
$index = 0;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (strlen($value) == 1) {
        $index++;
    } elseif (strlen($value) > 1) {
        if (!isset($new[$index])) {
            $new[$index] = null;
        }
        $new[$index] .= $value.' ';
    }
}
$new = array_values($new); // if 0, 1 index is important

print_r($new);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => B C 
    [1] => E F G H I J 
)
*/
```

Comment: You end up with a trailing space `'B C '` and `'E F G H I J '`

Comment: To fix that you can change this `if (!isset($new[$index])) { $new[$index] = $value;}else{$new[$index] .= ' '.$value;`

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
$a = ['A','B C','D','E F','G H','I J'];
$i = 0;

array_walk( $a, function($item) use (&$b,&$i){
    if( strlen($item) > 1){
        if(!isset($b[$i])){
            $b[$i] = $item;
        }else{
             $b[$i] .= " $item";
        }
    }else{
       ++$i; 
    }
});

var_export($b);
```

Try it [online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c0679f759b206b81926bb1c31e84b95c30f445ad)

Ouputs:

```
Array
(
   1 => 'B C',
   2 => 'E F G H I J',
)
```